# Package [zfsnap] installed incorrectly - what's what?

Tags: apt, package-management, zfs

On Ubuntu Xenial server, installing `zfsnap` exists with error status `0`. However, the package isn't properly installed:

```
$ zfsnap
zfsnap: command not found
$
$ sudo dpkg -p zfsnap
dpkg-query: package 'zfsnap' is not available
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
$
$ sudo dpkg -s zfsnap
Package: zfsnap
Status: install ok installed
Priority: extra
Section: admin
Installed-Size: 80
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: all
Version: 1.11.1-3
Depends: zfs-fuse | zfsutils | zfs, bc
```

Is there anything here (or something else I should look at) that suggests why the package isn't working properly?

---

Below is `apt`'s output for the installation:

```
$ sudo apt install zfsnap
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  bc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  bc zfsnap
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 20 not upgraded.
Need to get 97.9 kB of archives.
After this operation, 328 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Get:1 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 bc amd64 1.06.95-9build1 [82.6 kB]
Get:2 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 zfsnap all 1.11.1-3 [15.4 kB]
Fetched 97.9 kB in 1s (69.7 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package bc.
(Reading database ... 175968 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../bc_1.06.95-9build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking bc (1.06.95-9build1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package zfsnap.
Preparing to unpack .../zfsnap_1.11.1-3_all.deb ...
Unpacking zfsnap (1.11.1-3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for install-info (6.1.0.dfsg.1-5) ...
Setting up bc (1.06.95-9build1) ...
Setting up zfsnap (1.11.1-3) ...
$ echo $?
0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view a list of files included in a package with

```
dpkg-query -L zfsnap
```

To see the usable commands you could grep for /usr/bin or /usr/sbin in this case:

```
dpkg-query -L zfsnap|grep /usr/sbin
```

EDIT:
Catch-all with fancy regexp ;)

```
dpkg-query -L zfsnap|egrep "(/usr)*/(s*)bin"
```

Comment: I could not add a comment to the other answer due to lack of reputation, sorry ;)

Comment: I'd just `grep bin`, but `dpkg -L` is precisely what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
»» $ zfsnap
zfsnap: command not found ««
```

The package zfsnap provides `/usr/sbin/zfSnap` : Please note the upper case **S** in **zfSnap**.

Spelling, 1) Read the file list with `dpkg -L zfsnap`
2) Read online http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/all/zfsnap/filelist

Comment: Terrific! Just for future reference, however, how should one deduce that? `dpkg -S zfsnap` only finds the documentation (but, that **is** how the documentation entries are spelled); where's the clue that the executable of the `zfsnap` package is spelled `zfSnap`?

Comment: Please read my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks; if I hadn't up-voted already, I would now (@jr98 also mentioned the `-L` flag, so I don't want to un-accept his/her answer)

Comment: thank god newer versions don't have the capital S anymore.